How to I find out if a mac address is accessible?
I have a printer that has suddenly become inaccessible, and I can no longer connect to it. Suspecting DHCP, I configured it for a static IP address, so I know both the IP address and the MAC address.
Whenever I ping the IP address, on my Windows box, I get a Destination Host Unreachable.
I did a Ping from my OpnSense router, and got successful response. Then I did a Ping from my Windows box, and it returned host unreachable. At the same time, the OpnSense box started returning host unreachable too.
Both machines and the printer are plugged into ethernet ports on the same network switch.
While it's possible that the JetDirect card is failing, that seems unlikely.
When I do an arp -a on the OpnSense box, I see neither the mac address nor the IP address listed.
How do I confirm that the printer network interface is accessible on the network, and what should I consider when trying to work out why it is no longer accessible?
My current suspicion is some sort of security measure is kicking in, but I have no idea where to start diagnosing this problem.

Both machines and the printer are plugged into ethernet ports on the same network switch. Check the management interface of the switch for the MAC address in the ARP table.

Within the same IPv4 network segment arping - in a managed switch, check the port where the printer is connected and the arptable. - When the printer is missing try the cable,  it might have become loose and/or try with a replacement patch cable because even dumb cables can fail due to old age and/or excessive bending etc

Sniff the traffic - look for "who has" requests and replies. https://wiki.wireshark.org/AddressResolutionProtocol#example-traffic

Thanks all, I've tried plugging the printer into several ports on the switch, but apart from a few ports set to LAG, and one for a specific device on a VLAN (none of which I went near), the rest are just unrestricted ports. I looked at arping, but it didn't look useful, so I'll read up some more. Wireshark sounds like a good suggestion, so I'll check that out too. I'll update my question when I next get a chance to frob things.

arping will tell you if the mac address is connected to your LAN  - if it is not the answer perhaps you are asking the wrong question

Thanks @Jasen, when I was looking at arping it was before I'd made the printers IP address static, so it had a local link address, and I didn't see any point in trying to use that. It would be good to know if arping would have coped with that anyway though.

I would do it in following run tcpdump -v -n ether host [mac_address] and arp and try to see any what are the IP address request for an ARP. Example:
ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.11 tell 192.168.0.244, length 46
ARP, Reply 192.168.0.11 is-at 11:22:33:44:55:68, length 28

...or Wireshark (can't remember the mac filter syntax)
